# Recaptcha only showing up after page refresh - Rails 4 - Devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, recaptcha

I have installed recaptcha according to the gem instructions, however when I view the sign_up page (using Devise), the catcha doesn't appear until I refresh the page.

Looking through other comments, the recommendation is to disable turbolinks (which I am using) by changing the sign_in link to:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path, "data-no-turbolink" => true %><br />
```

I have tried this, but I still don't get the captcha until I do a page refresh.

Relevant code:

Views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
................
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
................
```

/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if !verify_recaptcha
     flash.delete :recaptcha_error
     build_resource
     resource.valid?
     resource.errors.add(:base, "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code.")
     clean_up_passwords(resource)
     respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new }
   else
    flash.delete :recaptcha_error
    super
   end
  end

  def clean_up_passwords(*args)
   # Delete or comment out this method to prevent the password fields from 
   # repopulating after a failed registration
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that I needed to still include "class:" in the link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, "data-no-turbolink" => true, class: "btn btn-primary btn-med" %>
```

Comment: You can say that more explicitly with `..._path, {"data-no-turbolink" => true}`

Answer (score 0):

Just try in controller this code

```
def create  
  if resource.valid? && !verify_recaptcha  
    clean_up_passwords(resource)  
    flash.delete :recaptcha_error   

  elsif !resource.valid? && verify_recaptcha  
    clean_up_passwords resource  
    respond_with resource  

  elsif !resource.valid? && !verify_recaptcha  
    flash.now[:alert] = "Recaptcha error"  
    flash.delete :recaptcha_error  
    clean_up_passwords resource  
    respond_with resource  

  end  
 end
```

And in your Views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= recaptcha_tags  display: {theme:  'red', tabindex:  5}, ssl: false, noscript: false %>
```

Comment: Same issue- the catcha only displays after a page reload